# Format Exception not handled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
    Dim labor, material, partstotal, labortotal, subtotal, tax, total As Decimal
    material = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
    labor = Decimal.Parse(LaborTextBox.Text)

    partstotal = material
    labortotal = labor * 50
    subtotal = labortotal + partstotal
    tax = subtotal * 0.08
    total = subtotal + tax

    partstotal = Decimal.Parse(PartsTextBox.Text)
    labortotal = Decimal.Parse(LaborTextBox.Text)
    subtotal = Decimal.Parse(SubTotalTextBox.Text)
    tax = Decimal.Parse(SalesTaxTextBox.Text)
    total = Decimal.Parse(TotalTextBox.Text)
```

material = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text) will not run. 
why?

Comment: What do you mean by do not run? It seems that it throws an exception, right? Copying and pasting the error here will help on getting good answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

What is the string value inside the text box?

[TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) will return an error instead of throwing.  Try that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking and labor = Decimal.Parse(LaborTextBox.Text) wont run either

Comment: @ScottESwingle It should be possible to capture the values of Text fields in the debugger, or simply copy-paste them from a form.  Exception happens likely due to user input that can't be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

What I think GregC is saying is that you need to use code like this:

```
Dim material As Decimal
If Not Decimal.TryParse(AmountTextBox.Text, material) Then
    ' the text in AmountTextBox could not be parsed as
    ' a Decimal.
    'TODO: do something about it.
End If
```

Although with that many items to validate, you might be able to provide a better user experience by using the [ErrorProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx).